# Graphically select geometric objects in a Jupyter/iPython notebook

Tags: javascript, python, jupyter, shapely, ipywidgets

The interoperability between Shapely and Jupyter/iPython is *nice*. I can do cool stuff like create a bunch of geometric shapes and view them in the notebook:

```
some_nodes = [[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2], [1, 0], [1, 1], [1, 2]]
some_boxes = []
some_boxes.append([some_nodes[0], some_nodes[3], some_nodes[4], some_nodes[1]])
some_boxes.append([some_nodes[1], some_nodes[4], some_nodes[5], some_nodes[2]])

from shapely.geometry import MultiPolygon, Polygon
MultiPolygon([Polygon(box) for box in some_boxes])
```

...and Jupyter will show me this:

[image: Jupyter_Shapely_output]

Now THAT is cool! It has been especially useful to me for quickly viewing and editing, for example, polygons that make up 2D finite element meshes.

Sadly, the images produced are just static SVG graphics; there's no interaction built in. It would be helpful to be able to select a subset of those objects in the image using this same graphical interface in iPython.

More specifically, I'd like to be able to create a list and add some of the displayed polygons to it by, for example, clicking/selecting them, or dragging a lasso/box around them, and also perhaps remove them when clicking a second time.

I've looked into trying to do this with matplotlib or javascript and although I've had some initial success it's probably the kind of project that is out of my depth at my current level of knowledge/skill.

Since Jupyter is a somewhat sprawling tool with lots of features that I am probably not aware of, I am wondering if there are already existing solutions out there for interaction of this sort in the context of a Jupyter notebook?

---

UPDATE#1: It looks like I'm going to have to create something myself. Happily, [this tutorial](https://youtu.be/o7Tb7YhJZR0?list=PLAshlHpA2IwdlMxzOJqwD1GEToQLAD7_vA) is going to make that a LOT easier.

UPDATE #2: It appears that Bokeh is a library much more suited for this purpose. I believe I am going to abandon the idea of creating custom Jupyter widgets and create an app using Bokeh widgets and interactions instead. Such an app can be used in a Jupyter notebook, but also elsewhere.

UPDATE #3: I ended up using the jupyter widget system anyway. Added my own answer showing a proof of concept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved this using vanilla javascript APIs and the [custom IPywidgets system](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/Widget%20Custom.html?). If you copy and paste this code, note that the cells are shown out of order. [Code is available here](https://github.com/Ricyteach/polygonselector).

### Usage

*(Cell #3)*

```py
import shapely.geometry as geo

some_nodes = [[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2], [1, 0], [1, 1], [1, 2]]
some_boxes = []
some_boxes.append([some_nodes[0], some_nodes[3], some_nodes[4], some_nodes[1]])
some_boxes.append([some_nodes[1], some_nodes[4], some_nodes[5], some_nodes[2]])

m_polygon = geo.MultiPolygon(geo.Polygon(box) for box in some_boxes)
poly_selector = PolygonSelector(m_polygon._repr_svg_())  # PolygonSelector defined below
poly_selector  # display the selector below cell, use the tool
```

Tool looks something like this:

[image]

After using the tool, you can obtain the currently selected polygon indices by copying the `groups_dict` attribute of the selector tool instance, which is "live":

*(Cell #4)*

```py
polygon_indexes = poly_selector.groups_dict.copy()
polygon_indexes
```

### Code

Work is still in progress, but below is an illustration of what I have ended up doing. Here also is a [link to the notebook on nbviewer](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/urls/dl.dropbox.com/s/vddslonje9lbh5v/Polygon%20Selector.ipynb) (the tool is not visible there).

I am putting this here partly for my own reference, but it's a proof of concept others can learn from (and improve upon). Some things aren't working the way I want-- such as changing colors of objects when they are selected. But the primary functionality, selecting and saving clicked polygons, works.

Below is the code cell by cell, as I have it in linked version above.

## Python Code

*(Cell #1)*

```
import ipywidgets.widgets as widgets
from traitlets import Unicode, Dict, List
from random import randint

class PolygonSelector(widgets.DOMWidget):
    _view_name = Unicode('PolygonSelectorView').tag(sync=True)
    _view_module = Unicode('polygonselector').tag(sync=True)
    groups_dict = Dict().tag(sync=True)
    current_list = List().tag(sync=True)
    content = Unicode().tag(sync=True)

    html_template = '''
    <style>
    # polygonGeometry path{{
        fill: 'pink';
    }}
    # polygonGeometry .selectedPolygon {{
        fill: {fill_selected!r};
    }}
    # polygonGeometry path:hover {{
        fill: {fill_hovered!r};
    }}
    {selection_styles}
    </style>
    <button id = "clearBtn"> Clear </button>
    <input placeholder = "Name this collection" id = "name" />
    <button id = "saveBtn"> Save </button>
    <div id = "polygonGeometry">{svg}</div>
    '''

    # provide some default colors; can override if desired
    fill_selected = "plum"
    fill_hovered = "lavender"
    group_colors = ["#{:06X}".format(randint(0,0xFFFFFF)) for _ in range(100)]

    def __init__(self, svg):
        super().__init__()
        self.update_content(svg)

    def update_content(self, svg):
        self.content = self.html_template.format(
            fill_selected = self.fill_selected,
            fill_hovered = self.fill_hovered,
            selection_styles = self.selection_styles,
            svg = svg
        )

    @property
    def selection_styles(self):
        return "".join(f'''
        # polygonGeometry .selection_{group_idx} {{
            fill: {self.group_colors[group_idx]!r};
        }}
        ''' for group_idx in range(len(self.groups_dict)))
```

## Javascript Code

*(Cell #2)*

```
%%javascript

require.undef('polygonselector');

define('polygonselector', ["@jupyter-widgets/base"], function(widgets) {

    var PolygonSelectorView = widgets.DOMWidgetView.extend({

        initialized: 0,

        init_render: function(){

        },


        // Add item to selection list
        add: function(id) {
          this.current_list.push(id);
          console.log('pushed #', id);
        },

        // Remove item from selection list
        remove: function(id) {
          this.current_list = this.current_list.filter(function(_id) {
            return _id !== id;
          })
          console.log('filtered #', id);
        },

        // Remove all items, closure
        clear: function(thisView) {
                return function() {
                    // `this` is the button element
                    console.log('clear() clicked');
                    thisView.el.querySelector('#name').value = '';
                    thisView.current_list.length = 0;
                    Array.from(thisView.el.querySelectorAll('.selectedPolygon')).forEach(function(path) {
                        console.log("path classList is: ", path.classList)
                        path.classList.remove('selectedPolygon');
                    })
                    console.log('Data cleared');
                    console.log(thisView.current_list)
                };
        },

        // Add current selection to groups_dict, closure
        save: function(thisView) {
                return function() {
                    // `this` is the button element
                    console.log('save() clicked');
                    const newName = thisView.el.querySelector('#name').value;
                    console.log('Current name: ', newName)
                    if (!newName || thisView.current_list.length < 1) {
                        console.log("Can't save, newName: ", newName, " list length: ", thisView.current_list.length)
                        alert('A new selection must have a name and selected polygons');
                    }
                    else {
                        console.log('Attempting to save....')
                        thisView.groups_dict[newName] = thisView.current_list.slice(0)
                        console.log('You saved some data');
                        console.log("Selection Name: ", newName);
                        console.log(thisView.groups_dict[newName]);
                        thisView.model.trigger('change:groups_dict');
                    }
                }
        },

        render: function() {
            PolygonSelectorView.__super__.render.apply(this, arguments);
            this.groups_dict = this.model.get('groups_dict')
            this.current_list = this.model.get('current_list')

            this.content_changed();
            this.el.innerHTML = `${this.model.get('content')}`;

            this.model.on('change:content', this.content_changed, this);
            this.model.on('change:current_list', this.content_changed, this);
            this.model.on('change:groups_dict', this.content_changed, this);

            // Each path element is a polygon
            const polygons = this.el.querySelectorAll('#polygonGeometry path');

            // Add click event to polygons
            console.log('iterating through polygons');
            var thisView = this
            let arr = Array.from(polygons)
            console.log('created array:', arr)
            arr.forEach(function(path, i) {
              console.log("Array item #", i)
              path.addEventListener('click', function() {
                console.log('path object clicked')
                if (thisView.current_list.includes(i)) {
                  path.classList.remove('selectedPolygon')
                  thisView.remove(i);
                  console.log('path #', i, ' removed');
                } else {
                  path.classList.add('selectedPolygon')
                  thisView.add(i);
                  console.log('path #', i, ' added');
                }
                thisView.content_changed();
              });
              console.log('path #', i, ' click set');
            });

            // Attach functions to buttons
            this.el.querySelector('#clearBtn').addEventListener('click', this.clear(this));
            console.log('clearBtn action set to current view context');
            this.el.querySelector('#saveBtn').addEventListener('click', this.save(this));
            console.log('saveBtn action set to current view context');

            console.log('render exit')

        },

        content_changed: function() {
            console.log('content changed');
            this.model.save();
            console.log("Current list: ", this.current_list);
            console.log("Groups dict: ", this.groups_dict);
        },
    });

    return {
        PolygonSelectorView : PolygonSelectorView
    };
});
```

Answer (score 2):

[Bokeh](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/) and [Plotly](https://plot.ly/) are two interactive python visualization libraries with support for spatial data. you can check out some examples ([1](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/gallery/texas.html), [2](https://plot.ly/python/#maps)) to see if this is what you are looking for. [This repository](https://github.com/UDST/vizicities) contains some very cool examples of 2D and 3D visualizations which you can run right in your jupyter notebook. You can also use GeoPandas and Folium to create fully interactive maps ([here](http://andrewgaidus.com/leaflet_webmaps_python/) is a great tutorial).

Answer (score 0):

Please also see the jp_doodle lasso tool.

Here it is as stand alone Javascript:

https://aaronwatters.github.io/jp_doodle/040_lasso.html

And here is how you use it from within a notebook:

https://github.com/AaronWatters/jp_doodle/blob/a809653b5bca98de70dc9524e703d95dc7c4067b/notebooks/Feature%20demonstrations/Lasso.ipynb

Hope you like!